# Resizing base64 to percentage of original in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, base64

I am rendering some base64 images in my react-native app, and it is working. However, right now it only seems to work when I assign a fixed height and width:

```
  <View>
    <Image
      source={{
        uri: logoStr,
      }}
      style={styles.logo}
    />
  </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // other styles
  logo: {
    width: 270,
    height: 320,
    marginTop: '10%',
  },
});
```

Since the images I'm using are not always exactly the same dimensions I'd like to use percentages rather than fixed pixel values. However, when I try something like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // other styles
  logo: {
    width: '25%',
    height: '25%',
    marginTop: '10%',
  },
});
```

... the image doesn't render at all.

I also tried this:

```
  logo: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.25,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.25,
    marginTop: '10%',
  },
```

... and I see the image, and the image shows the resized height correctly, but the width is clipped on either side. Ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to make the image 25% of the entire screen or 25% of the encapsulating View? If you are trying to if it into the entire screen you could use Dimensions.get('window').width * .25 and Dimensions.get('window').height * .25

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to render a smaller version of the original image. Please see what I tried above, based on your initial suggestion. With that implementation the image is clipped on either side, but is rendering correctly from top to bottom. The image can take up nearly all of the encapsulating view - but I'm unclear why I aways seem to end up with missing portions side to side, or top to bottom.

Comment: If pieces of the image are missing maybe you can change the resizeMode of your image to stretch to fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more what this would look like as an actual implementation?

Comment: I added an example in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
 <View>
   <Image
     source={{
       uri: logoStr,
     }}
     style={styles.logo}
     resizeMode={"contain"}
   />
 </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logo: {
     width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.25,
     height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.25,
     marginTop: '10%',
  },
});
```

Comment: This seems to work for most of the images - since most are longer than they are wide. But if for instance one of the images is a circle, it gets stretched lengthwise so it looks more like an oval. I want the original shape, but to a percentage of the original. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try changing the resize mode to contain. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [resizemode](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode) to control the scaling of an image, e.g. `cover`

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio)